# how to filter duplicate values based on other columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My table is something like as given below and i want to filter the duplicate com_id values 
depending on the other column values (temp_id and colors).

```
temp_id| com_id |colors                      
  1      1       Black
  2      1       Brown
  3      1       green
  4      2       red
  5      2       yellow
  6      2       white
  7      3       blue
  8      3       grey
  9      3       orange
```

And i want my result table should be something like given below:

```
temp_id com_id  colors
   1    1   Black 
   4    2   red
   7    3   blue
   2    1   Brown
   5    2   yellow
   8    3   grey
   3    1   green
   6    2   white
   9    3   orange
```

Comment: What is your question?  Based on what are you trying to filter?  The expected result is a reordered version of the first table?

Comment: you want filter or order com_id?

Comment: Based on temp_id and colors i want to order com_id.In my table com_id is category ids and temp_id is template ids so for ex: if i have 3 templates of temp_id(1,2,3) of category apparels (com_id:1,1,1).I want to order com_id in a way so that the duplicate values of com_id should not come together.First i want to display one set of com_id(1,2,3) and next(1,2,3) with fixed temp_id and colors as shown in 2nd table.